# How to disable onLongClick on ListView and inherit onLongClick from parent view?

Tags: android, listview

I have a view that looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:longClickable="true"
    tools:context="com.narudzba.myapplication.MainActivity">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and my activity looks somethnig like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
    linearLayout.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "HELLO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }
    });

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_item);
    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Message>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.activity_main));

}
```

My LinearLayout have onLongPressed() event, which is not triggered on ListView area, and i dont know why? I tried to set listview clickable on false, set duplicateStateParent on true, remove focus from ListView... but it not works.
Any advice to solve that onLongPressed event trigger on ListView area?

Comment: Hi Marko, yes of course it won't, listViews work as containers for list items, those items have a click property so disabling the property of the container view won't do much! FYI empty listViews are not clickable by default.

In-order to help u in this one we need to know the reason of adding an empty listView and are you planning on adding the items dynamically if so I think I've the answer if not! what is the purpose of the view then ?

Comment: My listview will be filled dynamically (ArrayAdapter) with listitems. Main reason what I want to do is that I want to implement onLongClick on whole  LinearLayout view.

Comment: then you just have to set the clickable property of each item to false; something similar to this:
public void addItems(View v) {
        v.setClickable(false);
         blabla......}